# Placing JS withing PHP var

Tags: php, javascript

I have a variable at the end of my PHP document, in the footer. However, because it is template the content of the variable is created in each page differently. Most of the contect of that variable is JS, that looks something like this:

```
  $myVar = '
    $(function() {
    '.$qTip.'

    $(".delDupe").click(function(){
        $(this).parent().find("input").val("");
        $(this).remove();
    });

    function custAxis() {
        if ($("#axisChk").is(":checked")){
            $(".customAxis").show();
        } else {
            $(".customAxis").hide();
        }
    }

    custAxis();
 });
```

This is just a small snippet of all JS. I would like to include this JS, still keeping it as a part of the PHP variable but outside of PHP. Is it possible?

```
$myVar = '?>
      // my JS
<? ';
```

Comment: Have you tried it?  What was the result?

Comment: Your bottom example of breaking out of a php variable cant be done like that, it will be interpreted as a string. I suggest you use heredoc

Comment: @tkone No, I have not tried this. I doubt it will work since my syntax is incorrect... I was looking for some suggestion of how to make it work. This = ' ?> is not going to work it would have to be = ''; ?> but that would make my variable empty.

Comment: @Lawrence Cherone Yes, that was just an attempt to clarify what I was asking. You're right, it won't work. How can I make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use this format:

```
$myVar = <<<EOD
Example of string
spanning multiple lines
using heredoc syntax.
EOD;
```

Comment: but how to insert the `$qTip` inside?

Comment: It's OK, I can copy actual code of that if I can make the rest work. EOD, hah? Never heard... I'll give it a whirl!

Answer (score 1):

You can use heredoc:

```
<?
$myVar = <<<END
$(function() {
....    
END;

echo $myVar;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use heredoc

```
<?php 
$myVar = <<<EOD
   $(".delDupe").click(function(){
        $(this).parent().find("input").val("");
        $(this).remove();
    });

    $qTip

    function custAxis() {
        if ($("#axisChk").is(":checked")){
            $(".customAxis").show();
        } else {
            $(".customAxis").hide();
        }
    }
EOD;
?>
```

Or you can use ob_start and break out of PHP and grab the output as a variable, this is how I load all my views/html

```
<?php
ob_start();
?>
  $(".delDupe").click(function(){
        $(this).parent().find("input").val("");
        $(this).remove();
    });

    <?=$qTip;?>

    function custAxis() {
        if ($("#axisChk").is(":checked")){
            $(".customAxis").show();
        } else {
            $(".customAxis").hide();
        }
    }
<?php
$myVar = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
echo $myVar;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the JavaScript into the html and output that $qTip string from php. It's more or less the same effect as the one you did, just written in another way.

```
$(function() {
<?=$qTip?>

$(".delDupe").click(function(){
    $(this).parent().find("input").val("");
    $(this).remove();
});

function custAxis() {
    if ($("#axisChk").is(":checked")){
        $(".customAxis").show();
    } else {
        $(".customAxis").hide();
    }
}

custAxis();
});
```